# Permission to read /cache/recovery/last_log

Tags: android, android-permissions

Which permission an app need to access the file /cache/recovery/last_log?

My app is signed with platform key, so I can provide system permissions. The app will be pre-built into a device, and the device will be non-rooted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution some time ago, just posting here to help if someone else have the same problem.

The thing that was blocking me was SELinux. I'm posting the solution to the original question, but be aware that some things changed on Android since that, including the creation of the [A/B system](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/ab/ab_implement), where the recovery and cache partitions where removed from Android.

## SELinux

I learned the hard way that one have to deal with SELinux in order to work on the Android source code. The important bits are:

1. On the device definition (makefiles under the *device* directory) there will be reference to SELinux policies. In one of the devices I work with I have a makefile that have:

   BOARD_SEPOLICY_DIRS += path/to/sepolicy/dir

And on the directory all files with ".te" ending will be used as SEPolicy. I suggest adding a new directory for your custom policies, where you can use your own git repository.

Now you need to know what policies to write. I suggest reading Google's documentation [here](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/device-policy).

Personally, I first test the app on a *userdebug* build with SELinux in permissive mode (log only). These way SELinux will only log actions that violates the policies, what makes development substantially easier. Only after I know the app runs with SELinux off I start collecting the logs and set the "enforced" mode.

To collect the SELinux logs of actions that don't met the policies I use:

```
adb logcat | grep "avc: denied"
```

There is a tool called *audit2allow* that reads the logcat output and the device policy and outputs policies that are missing:

```
adb pull /sys/fs/selinux/policy
adb logcat -b all -d | python2 audit2allow -p policy
```

The output of the file are policies that can be added to the *.te* files.

This particular method I used with Android 8.1.

## Sign app with platform key

I also had to sign the app with the platform key. For that I edited Android.mk to add:

```
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
```

## System UID

Fixing SELinux policy might not be enough for some device. You might need to make the app run with the system user.

**You must avoid using these method**, because this user have access to some very sensitive device files. If you really need, you can do it by:

1. Sign the app with platform key;
2. On the app that will read the recovery, you have to make sure AndroidManifest.xml set android:sharedUserID to "android.uid.system".

```xml
<manifest package="my.app.name"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system">
....
</manifest>
```

## Other useful files

Other files of interest to diagnose boot and ota problems are documented [here](http://www.althority.com/getting_android_logs/).

Answer (score 0):

You can only access the cache directory for your app

```
getApplicationContext().getCacheDir()
```

Apparantly, you don't need any permission to READ from cache. But you do need permission if you want to write something in cache directory.

Documentation from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_LOGS on logs:

```
Allows an application to read the low-level system log files.
Not for use by third-party applications, because Log entries can contain the user's private information.
Constant Value: "android.permission.READ_LOGS"
```

What do you mean by 'recovery'?

Comment: I'm writing the software that updates the Android OS. It's the software that runs when you go to settings/about/system updates. It downloads the android image from a web server, validates it and demands Android to get updated by it. After that the operating system will reboot into recovery mode and apply the patch. That will, for example turn a 4.4 android into a 5. The recovery partition writes on /cache/recovery directory, so I have no choice, I need to read logs from there.